# How to use flags while compiling Kernel Modules

Tags: c, makefile, freebsd, kernel-module

I need to use some optimization and loop unrolling flags for my kernel module. But I don't know how to add these flags to the makefile.

```
KMOD= hello   # Name of KLD to build
SRCS= hello.c # List of source files

.include <bsd.kmod.mk>
```

I tried to google search but didn't get anything I could use. Thank you for your time.

**Edit 1:**
*I am doing some kernel memory patching on a loop. So I don't want the loops to unroll as that would mean more patching.*

I have tried

```
KMOD= hello   # Name of KLD to build
SRCS= hello.c # List of source files
CFLAGS = -O0 -fno-unroll-loops #tried combination of this and +=
.include <bsd.kmod.mk>
```

I have also tried, (I know this is just wishful thinking)

```
make DEBUG_FLAGS = -O0 -fno-unroll-loops
```

Comment: Did you try sth. like `CFLAGS += -O3 -funroll-loops`?

Comment: After you asked this, I realised my question was incomplete in that, that I hadn't provided what things I had tried and what my exact intention was. Apologies, I will add more details to question. Thank you.

Comment: The FreeBSD devs hang out on the mailing lists. Did you ask this over there?

Comment: Got the answer. Thank you. No, I did not ask. But Can you tell me more about this mailing list? @Rob

Comment: As always, consult the excellent [FreeBSD Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/eresources-mail.html)

Comment: You might be interested in [The Porter's Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/porters-handbook/) also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for wasting people's time. I got the answer.

```
KMOD= hello
SRCS= hello.c
CFLAGS= -O0
.include <bsd.kmod.mk>
```

*P.S Please take care of spacing*

Thank you

@[Ctx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5636775/ctx) for suggesting the solution in question comments

AND

@[Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/162698/rob) for providing/reminding where the resources for people are, who jump to questions without doing due diligence(like me)

**Resources:**

[FreeBSD devs Mailing List](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/eresources-mail.html)

[FreeBSD Porter's Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/porters-handbook/)